# curl, gem install failed to connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm

I've looked at all the possible answers on google and I just can't figure this out. I'm literally going insane here!

I'm running osx lion and have ruby & rubyGems installed but whenever i try and run:

```
gem install rails
```

even with a sudo I get :

```
WARNING:  Error fetching data: Host is down - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
WARNING:  Error fetching data: Host is down - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
Host is down - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/gems/i18n-0.6.0.gem)
```

and then when i try install rvm using :

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

I get :

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 208.85.148.213: Host is down
```

now I'm not very good with the whole terminal thing so maybe it's me but i'm not behind a proxy and firewall is turned off.

I have checked gems sources and it's correct.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you access `get.rvm.io` in the browser?

Comment: Yes I can access get.rvm.io just fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like a firewall issue - do you have something like LittleSnitch or Hands Off! installed? If so, disable them and try again; you likely have a rule blocking access from shell.

A quick google search shows [at least one other person](http://aminsblog.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/mac-os-x-host-is-down-with-curl-python-pipetc/) has the issue you're having and had a firewall rule blocking access.

Comment: Thanks my requests were blocked by LittleSnitch, but message is a bit confusing.

Comment: LittleSnitch was my issue here too. I had upgraded but yet to restart so it defaulted to blocking it without an option to allow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, this sounds like a connection issue on your end. Verify your firewall and try running some traceroutes. Your DNS settings appear to be somewhat correct since your lookup of rvm.io returns the same IP for me.